# Could executing OpenGL shaders sent from a server be dangerous?

Tags: opengl, shaders, networking, client-server, security

I just came to the realization that since uncompiled shaders are just text, they can easily be sent over a network from a server and then compiled at runtime and executed on clients. I'm not actually planning on doing this (probably...), but I am curious as to whether or not it would result in any potential security vulnerabilities on the clients executing the shaders.

My gut feeling is that it would not, since even if a shader were to gain unauthorized access (eg by reading unallocated data from a video buffer), it would have no way of sending this data back to the attacker. On the other hand, allowing arbitrary code execution seems like an almost certain way to get hacked. My question is how this would be possible in this scenario (assuming that it is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the difficulty of successfully exploiting a machine through shaders is pretty difficult but not impossible or unprecedented.

There's a small chance of that happening -- for example, there was an OSX vulnerability that enabled RCE or crashes http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2016-1847/ but the vulnerability itself could be either from the GL library  [Memory safety errors in libGLES in the ANGLE graphics library](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2015-113/) or on the application side improperly handling bound buffer memory that could possibly be written to in the shader [Buffer overflow in WebGL after out of memory allocation](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2016-03/)

Another vulnerability is that the shader could access other bits of graphics memory that are shared by the window manager or other applications, allowing it to perhaps be able to read the contents of your other windows. Exfiltration could be a stretch, but either low-quality drivers could allow the malicious shader to write to uncontrolled memory or you could use steganography to embed screenshots of other windows in the current game screenshots.

Comment: Nice answer. Even if the shader was able to write back to uncontrolled memory, it would still need to then send that data back to the attacker somehow, right?

Comment: @PandaConda all it needs to do is crash the client and you have a denial of service attack.

Comment: Yes, and additionally, oftentimes when you can crash a client, it's because you wrote some garbage instructions into an executable page or had arbitrary memory writes that tried to write into a read-only memory segment. Either one, with careful analysis, could be used to weaken the system and escalate to code execution.